# Union All MySQL Statement for 3 Tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the information to display from 3 different tables with the same column structure.  I know to use the Union All in sql but when I write this out I get 0 results.  No errors or anytihng just nothing populates.

```
$sql = 'SELECT
Invoice_
FROM
(
  SELECT
        RQ.Invoice_

        FROM disc_rq_activations RQ
        LEFT JOIN disc_Activations VZ
          ON LEFT(RQ.Related_SN,length(RQ.Related_SN)-1)  = VZ.Device_ID
          WHERE VZ.Device_ID IS NULL
          AND VZ.Purchased_Receivable IS NULL
          AND RQ.District = "'.$region.'"

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
       U.Invoice_

       FROM disc_rq_upgrades U
       LEFT JOIN disc_Upgrades VZ
       ON LEFT(U.Related_SN,length(U.Related_SN)-1) = VZ.Device_ID
       WHERE VZ.Device_ID IS NULL
       AND U.District = "'.$region.'"

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
       O.Invoice_

       FROM disc_rq_optional_services O
       LEFT JOIN disc_optional_services VZ
       ON LEFT(O.Related_SN,length(O.Related_SN)-1) = VZ.Device_ID
       WHERE VZ.Device_ID IS NULL
       AND O.District = "'.$region.'"


) ';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($admin);

#}

$stmt->bindColumn(1,  $Invoice_);
$stmt->bindColumn(2,  $amount);




$stmt->execute();
$numRows = $stmt->rowCount();


if (isset($numRows)) {
```

Tables:

```
Activations
+----------+--------+
| Invoice_ | Amount |
+----------+--------+
|    86754 | $10.00 |
|    63729 | $20.00 |
|    92647 | $30.00 |
|          |        |
+----------+--------+

Upgrades
+----------+---------+
| Invoice_ | Amount  |
+----------+---------+
|    86754 | $48.00  |
|     7373 | $67.00  |
|    76970 | $300.00 |
|          |         |
+----------+---------+

Opt Services
+----------+--------+
| Invoice_ | Amount |
+----------+--------+
|     3245 | $66.00 |
|     4567 | $15.00 |
|      345 | $32.00 |
+----------+--------+
```

The goal is to display all on one page.  Currently, they are all separated into different pages which make for more work.

In my current query I only selected 1 column for testing purposes.

Where am I going wrong with this query?

Desired Outcome:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| Invoice_ | Amount  |    Table     |
+----------+---------+--------------+
|    86754 | $10.00  | Activations  |
|    63729 | $20.00  | Activations  |
|    92647 | $30.00  | Activations  |
|    86754 | $48.00  | upgrades     |
|     7373 | $67.00  | upgrades     |
|    76970 | $300.00 | upgrades     |
|     3245 | $66.00  | Opt Services |
|     4567 | $15.00  | Opt Services |
|      345 | $32.00  | Opt Services |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Using the answer supplied still gives no data.

```
$sql = 'SELECT Invoice_, "Activations" as table from `Activations`
UNION ALL
SELECT Invoice_, "Upgrades" as table from `Upgrades`
UNION ALL
SELECT Invoice_, "Opt Services" as table from `Opt Services`

';
```

Full Working Code:

```
SELECT
   Invoice_,
   Tracking_,
   Qty,
   Product_SKU,
   Product_Name,
   Unit_Rebate,
   Related_Product,
   Related_SKU,
   Related_SN,
   Related_Cost,
   Related_Price,
   Rate_Plan,
   Customer,
   Sales_Person,
   Sales_Person_ID,
   Sold_On,
   Invoiced_At,
   Original_Invoice,
   Original_Sales_Date,
   Contract_,
   SOC_Code,
   SOC_Code_2,
   Extra_Field,
   Port_Number,
   Region,
   District,
   Vendor_Account_Name,
   'activations' as a 
from
   `disc_rq_activations` 
   LEFT JOIN
      disc_Activations VZ 
      ON LEFT(Related_SN, length(Related_SN) - 1) = VZ.Device_ID 
WHERE
   VZ.Device_ID IS NULL 
   AND VZ.Purchased_Receivable IS NULL 
   AND District = '".$region."' 
UNION ALL
SELECT
   Invoice_,
   Tracking_,
   Qty,
   Product_SKU,
   Product_Name,
   Unit_Rebate,
   Related_Product,
   Related_SKU,
   Related_SN,
   Related_Cost,
   Related_Price,
   Rate_Plan,
   Customer,
   Sales_Person,
   Sales_Person_ID,
   Sold_On,
   Invoiced_At,
   Original_Invoice,
   Original_Sales_Date,
   Contract_,
   SOC_Code,
   SOC_Code_2,
   Extra_Field,
   Port_Number,
   Region,
   District,
   Vendor_Account_Name,
   'upgrades' as b 
from
   `disc_rq_upgrades` 
   LEFT JOIN
      disc_Upgrades VZ 
      ON LEFT(Related_SN, length(Related_SN) - 1) = VZ.Device_ID 
WHERE
   VZ.Device_ID IS NULL 
   AND District = '".$region."' 
UNION ALL
SELECT
   Invoice_,
   Tracking_,
   Qty,
   Product_SKU,
   Product_Name,
   Unit_Rebate,
   Related_Product,
   Related_SKU,
   Related_SN,
   Related_Cost,
   Related_Price,
   Rate_Plan,
   Customer,
   Sales_Person,
   Sales_Person_ID,
   Sold_On,
   Invoiced_At,
   Original_Invoice,
   Original_Sales_Date,
   Contract_,
   SOC_Code,
   SOC_Code_2,
   Extra_Field,
   Port_Number,
   Region,
   District,
   Vendor_Account_Name,
   'optionalServices' as c 
from
   `disc_rq_optional_services` 
   LEFT JOIN
      disc_optional_services VZ 
      ON LEFT(Related_SN, length(Related_SN) - 1) = VZ.Device_ID 
WHERE
   VZ.Device_ID IS NULL 
   AND District = '".$region."'
```

Comment: The super query appears to be redundant, and see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: And note that (while sometimes unavoidable) joining on a function is often an indication of poor design.

Comment: Which is all by way of preamble to asking you to show us what the desired result should actually look like.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated my OP for the expected outcome

Comment: Yep - no idea why you're making such a meal of this!!!

Comment: Your code is a copy/paste victim. Replace all those `RQ` aliases from the 2nd and 3d of your unioned queries with `U` and `O`.

Comment: @forpas Yeah I fixed that but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you need any subqueries for this. Try the below:

Data:

```
+----------+--------+
| Invoice_ | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| 92647    | 30     |
| 86754    | 10     |
| 63729    | 20     |
+----------+--------+

+----------+--------+
| Invoice_ | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| 86754    | 48     |
| 7373     | 67     |
| 76970    | 300    |
+----------+--------+

+----------+--------+
| Invoice_ | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| 3245     | 66     |
| 4567     | 15     |
| 345      | 32     |
+----------+--------+
```

Query:

```
select Invoice_, Amount, 'Activations' as table from `Activations`
union all
select Invoice_, Amount, 'Upgrades' as table from `Upgrades`
union all
select Invoice_, Amount, 'Opt Services' as table from `Opt Services`;
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| Invoice_ | Amount | Activations  |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 92647    | 30     | Activations  |
| 86754    | 10     | Activations  |
| 63729    | 20     | Activations  |
| 86754    | 48     | Upgrades     |
| 7373     | 67     | Upgrades     |
| 76970    | 300    | Upgrades     |
| 3245     | 66     | Opt Services |
| 4567     | 15     | Opt Services |
| 345      | 32     | Opt Services |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: @DavidMorin Note that this is possibly a better design than your existing set-up; you might consider revising your schema accordingly.

Comment: Possibly the backtics

Comment: Yeah this still gives me 0 data.

Comment: @DavidMorrin: works like a charm for me.. I added in and output to my answer just in case. The backticks are really optional - alternatively you can rename `Opt Services` to anything without a space... but this should not cause an error anyway

Comment: @DavidMorrin: also, depending on where you run this you might want to specify your db

Comment: @LeroyFromBerlin I tried your solution but still nothign.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e79707/2

Comment: Ok I think i got the answer here.  I needed to remove Table from the statement and replace it with something unique.